# How to use exceptions for queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to handle errors in MySQL queries as exceptions.

For example, if I am inserting a record but a column is not in the table then it will show me an error.
Is there any way to handle it so that the user won't be able to see the error?

Answer (score 1):

CI has no good support for exceptions.You need to do is setup proper exception handling.

Now all your database errors will automatically throw exceptions. And as a bonus you have good exception handling in your entire CI application.

Register a custom errorhandler that transforms PHP errors into exceptions, for instance put this in top of your config/config.php

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno))
    {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    log_message('error', "$errstr @$errfile::$errline($errno)" );
    throw new ErrorException( $errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline );
}

set_error_handler("my_error_handler");
```

Register an uncaught exception handler, put something like this in your `config/config.php`

```
function my_exception_handler($exception)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($exception);
    echo '</pre>';
    header( "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error" );
}
set_exception_handler("my_exception_handler");
```

Set a termination handler:

```
function my_fatal_handler()
{
    $errfile = "unknown file";
    $errstr  = "Fatal error";
    $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
    $errline = 0;
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ( $error !== NULL )
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($error);
        echo '</pre>';
        header( "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error" );
    }
}
register_shutdown_function("my_fatal_handler");
```

Set a custom assert handler that converts asserts into exceptions, put something like this in your `config/config.php`:

```
function my_assert_handler($file, $line, $code)
{
    log_message('debug', "assertion failed @$file::$line($code)" );
    throw new Exception( "assertion failed @$file::$line($code)" );
}
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE,     1);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING,    0);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,       0);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'my_assert_handler');
```

Use wrappers like this in your controllers

```
public function controller_method( )
{
    try
    {
        // normal flow
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        log_message( 'error', $e->getMessage( ) . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() );
        // on error
    }
}
```

You can tune and customize the whole thing to your likings!

Hope this helps.

You will also need to intercept the CI show_error method. Place this in `application/core/MY_exceptions.php`:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        log_message( 'debug', print_r( $message, TRUE ) );
        throw new Exception(is_array($message) ? $message[1] : $message, $status_code );
    }
}
```

And leave in `application/config/database.php` this setting on `FALSE` to have database errors converted into exceptions.

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```